# How to install gvim?

Tags: gvim

I have done the following:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

But I get the following:

```
vim-gnome : Depends: libruby1.8 (>= 1.8.7.352) but 1.8.6.111-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've done:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Contents of my /etc/apt/sources.list file:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security multiverse
```

But all to no avail.  I always get the same error above.

What can I do to resolve?

Comment: I wonder why is your libruby still at 1.8.6? The ubuntu repositories contain 1.8.7 (http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/libruby1.8). Are you using the main repository? Enter `gnome-control-center software` and see the „Download from” setting.

Comment: It's set to download from Server for United States.

Comment: does running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` help?

Comment: You can try to set it to „Main server” and do an update, just to exclude the case that your repository is not up-to-date. If it does not help set it back, it eases the load on the main servers.

Comment: Changing to main server didn't help.  it allowed dist-upgrade to run without any errors, but I still have the same situation when trying to install vim

Comment: Can you edit your question with the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: Could you run `dpkg --get-selections | grep libruby` and update the question with the output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to check your sources. I see that `libruby1.8 1.8.7.352-2` is available through `main` while it seems that the newest version you have is: `1.8.6.111-2ubuntu1`. This probably means that you `dist-upgrade` failed or that you still need to `update` your sources.

```
$ apt-cache policy libruby1.8
libruby1.8:
  Installed: 1.8.7.352-2
  Candidate: 1.8.7.352-2
  Version table:
 *** 1.8.7.352-2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: How do I update the sources?  I've already tried doing the apt-get install update/upgrade...  The dist-upgrade fails with the same error I posted in the original question.

Comment: From which distribution are you upgrading? That should help to know if there's any known problem. I've checked the `libruby1.8` package version in natty and looks like you're upgrading from an older distribution.

Comment: I'm afraid you're getting over my head.  I can't even remember what I've upgraded (I've done several upgrades on this little used installation).

Comment: Looking at [hardy](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hardy/+package/libruby1.8) and [intrepid](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/intrepid/+package/libruby1.8), I'd say that you're getting a version from hardy (you could still see that using `apt-cache policy libruby1.8` as I did above anyway). The recommended upgrade path would be upgrade to the next LTS and later to the next following distro: 8.04 (LTS) -> 10.04 (LTS) -> 10.10 -> 11.04 -> 11.10. Those are probably too many upgrades, so I'd advice to backup your home directory and install oneiric 11.10 from scratch.

Answer (score 36):

On Ubuntu 20.04 (since [`vim-gnome` was removed in 19.10](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/tree/debian/changelog?h=ubuntu/eoan#n140)):

```
sudo apt install vim-gtk3
```

Answer (score 31):

The following worked for me:

run this

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then run

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1234566/527764) for recent versions of Ubuntu that don't have this package

Comment: @Zanna thanks, `sudo apt install vim-gtk3` on Ubuntu 20.04 and above.

Answer (score 4):

in Ubuntu 16.04 it should be:

```
sudo apt update
```

and then

```
sudo apt install vim-gnome
```

Answer (score 2):

**What worked for me** :

```
sudo apt remove vim-common
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```